# Independent variables using covariance matrix

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Let $X = (X_1,X_2)^T$ be a bivariate random variable with covariance matrix

$$ W = \begin{pmatrix} 4&0.6 \\ 0.6&1 \end{pmatrix} $$

You are given $X_1 + \alpha X_2 $ is independent of $X_1$. Find $\alpha$

I know that for independence we have $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2}(x_2)$

Comment: **Hint:** If $\xi_1$, $\xi_2$ are two independent variables what is their covariance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me use $(X,Y)$ instead of $(X_1,X_2)$ to simplify notation

Using the given independence you have that

$$\mathbb{Cov}[X+aY;X]=0$$

that is

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2+aXY]-\mathbb{E}[X+aY]\cdot\mathbb{E}[X]=0$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]+a\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]-a\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$$

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=-a\mathbb{Cov}[X,Y]$$

$$a=-\frac{4}{0.6}=-\frac{20}{3}$$